# rubyのfor文にはeach_index的なものはないのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby

#### pythonのfor文

```
ary = ["taguti","fkoji"]
for i in range(len(ary)):
    print(i)
```

#### rubyの場合はeach_index

```
ary = ["taguti","fkoji"]
ary.each_index{|i| p i}
```

#### rubyのfor文にそのような機能はあるのでしょうか？

```
for i in ary.length
  p i# --- NG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubyの場合はfor式をほとんど使いません

- スコープの扱いが特殊で変なバグを産みかねない
- forがeachを使って実装されてるので単純に遅い

[each_index](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Array/i/each_index.html)でいいのではないでしょうか

```
ary = %w[taguti fkoji]
ary.each_index{|i| p i}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。今読んでいる書籍にもforはeachを使って実装していると書いてありました。pythonから本格的にはじめたもんですか、単純にfor文でインデックスループできるのか気になりました。

Answer (score 0):

OTL　よくよく考えたら普通にできました。

#### 回答

```
ary = ["taguti", "fkoji"]
for i in 0..ary.length do
  p i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと違うかもですが、 添字つき each を行いたい場合は、 each_with_index を使うのが、一般的かなと思います。

```
[3,2,1].each_with_index do |e,i|
  puts "#{i}: #{e}"
end
0: 3
1: 2
2: 1
=> [3, 2, 1]
```